# How do I write strings to the iOS Notes.app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my app, I have several strings that I would like to programatically turn into notes in the iOS Notes.app.

I have done the part of calling Modal View of Notes.

Comment: Music notes? School notes? ...

Comment: It's Difficult to trace your question. Please provide more explanation.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: the one required for writing or saving your texts,

Comment: @NajeebullahShah: Based on the answer you've accepted, I've edited your question to be clearer about what I *think* you're asking about. I have left the second sentence (the "…Modal View…" one) alone, because I have absolutely no clue what that means (but I'm not an iOS developer, so that may just be me). Please feel free to clean up further—or, alternatively, to revert my edit if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @derobert: thanx you have somehow saved me from furthur -ves hahahaha,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean because your question is too general, but if you refer to `Notes.app` that ships with iOS - it has no URL scheme so it's not possible to communicate with the app in any way, nor is it possible to save notes there.